# ElasticSearch how to ensure that all words are involved in search

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

Let's say I have an index in ElasticSearch 6:

```
"mappings" : {
  "pet" : {
      "name" : {
         "type" : "text"
      },          
      "info" : {
         "type" : "text"
      },
      "description" : {
         "type" : "text"
      }
   }
}
```

I need to perform full-text search by all fields with the same input string that is typed by user: 'big grey dog' or 'small cute cat'. How can I up in relevance search those units, which contain more words from input. No matter where - name or description. I want that unit:

```
{
    "name" : "big",
    "info" : "grey",
    "description" : "dog" 
}
```

have higher score then unit:

```
{
    "name" : "grey dog",
    "info" : "dog dog grey dog",
    "description" : "grey dog grey dog grey dog" 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `multiMatch` query you should use the `cross_field` type with `AND` operator ([see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields)).

But as it will only match document containing all terms you should use a `bool query` with two `should` clauses, a loose clause with a default type ( aka `best_fields` ) and default `OR` operator and a strict one with type `cross_field` and operator `AND`.

With this it will boost documents matching all field, and continue to display with lower score document only matching some terms :

Something like :

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "<here your query>",
            "fields": ["name", "info", "description"],
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "operator": "AND"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "<here your query>",
            "fields": ["name", "info", "description"],
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```